# Animation starts slowly and get faster with time ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, duration, animatewithduration

i am trying to animate the rotation of an imageview. it is rotating and animating but my animation start slowly and it speed up with time
lets say i am performing animation with 5 seconds duration then first 1-2 seconds my image is rotating slowly but as time gets closer to 5 it speeds up here is my code

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, delay:0 , options: .Repeat , animations: {
//fan is UIImageView
        self.fan.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
    }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default animation curve is `.CurveEaseInOut`. You want `.CurveLinear`.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, delay:0, options: [.Repeat, .CurveLinear] , animations: {
//fan is UIImageView
        self.fan.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: it was giving an error because of [ ] but i handled it with my own logic. thanks a  lot for quick response